# How to stop Powershell 7 ConvertFrom-Json reformatting timestamps?

Tags: json, powershell

```
Get-Content 'file.json' | ConvertFrom-Json
```

This produces a different result for powershell 5 vs 7.

```
v5 gives me actual timestamp values from the json: eg 2018-01-26T17:48:51.220Z
v7 gives me reprocessed timestamp values from the json  eg 26/01/2018 17:48:51
```

How can I get v7 to behave as v5? I need the original values from the json.

Comment: Oh, ps 7 converts it to a datetime object.

Comment: I am wondering why a string would be preferable to a `DateTime`.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I'm checking a value that appears in json also appears in a another file (parquet)

Comment: So you can use `ConvertFrom-Json` for both and compare the timestamps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior of `ConvertFrom-Json` changed in **PowerShell [Core] v6+**: ***string* values formatted with  the [`o` (round-trip) standard date/time format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier) are now converted to [`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)) instances** rather than being parsed as strings - this is a convenient way to round-trip timestamps via (v6+) `ConvertTo-Json`, without having to do explicit to/from string conversions.

If you need the old behavior back, convert the resulting `[datetime]` instances back to strings explicitly, using `.ToString('o')`.

Here's a simple example:

```
# v6+
PS> ('{ "timestamp": "2018-01-26T17:48:51.220Z" }' | 
       ConvertFrom-Json).timestamp.ToString('o')

2018-01-26T17:48:51.2200000Z
```

- There is *some* flexibility around variations in the *input* format: the *fractional* seconds are optional, and if, present, the number of decimal places is allowed to vary.
- By contrast, the `o` format always uses *7* decimal places, which differs from your input.

  - You're free to apply custom formatting based on a *fixed* number of decimal places, but note that you won't be able to tell how many decimal places were actually used *in the input*.

    - E.g., to get 3 decimal places:
      `[datetime]::UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffK")`
- If you want to prevent the to-`[datetime]` conversion *at the source*, you'll have to use a lower-level approach - `ConvertFrom-Json` doesn't offer a solution.